# Bullseye With alternating colors

Tags: java, swing, colors

Im trying to make a bullseye with alternating colors but everytime I run this code I get one uniform color. I tried using repaint() at the end of the for loop but it didn't help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Unit5Activity1 extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Color color1 = new Color(100, 199, 100);
        Color color2 = new Color(208, 180, 45);

        for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--){
            if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5) {
                g.setColor(color1);
                g.fillOval(250 + i*25, 250 + i*25, 250 - 50*i, 250 - 50*i);
            }

            else if(i == 2 || i == 4){
                g.setColor(color2);
                g.fillOval(250 + i*25, 250 + i*25, 250 - 50*i, 250 - 50*i);
            }
        }
    }   





    public static void main(String[] args){
        Unit5Activity1 panel = new Unit5Activity1();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize(500, 500);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }//main

}//class
```

Answer (score 3):

```
g.fillOval(250 + i*25, 250 + i*25, 250 - 50*i, 250 - 50*i);
```

Don't do math calculations in the parameters of a method. When you do this you can't verify if the calculations are correct.

Instead create variables and use the variables in the calculation then you can debug your code to see if it is working the way you expect.

So your code should be something like:

```
for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
{
    int x = 250 + i*25;
    int y = x;
    int width = 250 - 50*i;
    int height = width;
    System.out.println(x + " : " + width);

    if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5) 
    {
        g.setColor(color1);
    }

    else if(i == 2 || i == 4)
    {
        g.setColor(color2);
    }

    g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
}
```

You want to paint the largest circle first. So each time through the loop:

1. the x/y values should increase and
2. the width/height should decrease

Now you can verify is your logic is correct or not.